# How put title in a "Dedication"

Tags: titles

I want to put the title bigger and make it nice
my code have this result, but i need more the title

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
   \itshape             % the text is in italics
   \raggedleft          % flush to the right margin
  }
  {\par % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to google and wikipedia by models (SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS), the CP provides the storage and processing facilities
needed to support that service model, together with a cloud interface for cloud
service consumers. For SaaS, the CP deploy
\end{dedication}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "[you] need more the title"?

Comment: @Werner my english is not very good, 
I just want to put the title

Comment: That's fine. "Putting" the title is exactly what is happening though. By "more" I imagine you want something bigger? How about typing your question in [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) and then posting it here...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you simply needs to add `\section*{Dedication}` at the right place in your definition.

Please see the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
  \section*{Dedication} % <==========================================
   \itshape             % the text is in italics
   \raggedleft          % flush to the right margin
  }
  {\par % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to google and wikipedia by models (SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS), the CP provides the storage and processing facilities
needed to support that service model, together with a cloud interface for cloud
service consumers. For SaaS, the CP deploy
\end{dedication}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: dedication with title]

To get the title left simply move `\raggedleft` before `\section*`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
   \raggedleft          % flush to the right margin <===============
   \section*{Dedication} % <========================================
   \itshape             % the text is in italics

  }
  {\par % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to google and wikipedia by models (SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS), the CP provides the storage and processing facilities
needed to support that service model, together with a cloud interface for cloud
service consumers. For SaaS, the CP deploy
\end{dedication}
\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image: title left]

Comment: The font is distint, How can I put it on the left? in another example please

Comment: but when I put section the alignment was modified

Comment: i put \leftskip=5cm
   \parindent=10pt to align the paragraph of the dedication, but when i put \section the align change

Comment: see please my new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476651/how-put-title-in-dedicatory