# How put title in dedicatory?

Tags: titles

I want to put the title bigger, 
without losing the alignment of the paragraph of the dedication

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
   \raggedleft
   \leftskip=5cm
   \parindent=10pt
   \itshape             % the text is in italics

  }
  {\par % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to google and wikipedia by models (SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS), the CP provides the storage and processing facilities
needed to support that service model, together with a cloud interface for cloud
service consumers. For SaaS, the CP deploy
\end{dedication}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use *scoping* (using `{`...`}` or `\begingroup`...`\endgroup`) to limit the effect of `\raggedleft`, or you can use `\justifying` from [`ragged2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) to restore the justified look of a paragraph after something like `\raggedleft` or `\centering`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
   \raggedleft          % Flush with right margin
   \section*{Dedication}% Formatting of dedication title (as section*)
   \itshape             % the text is in italics
   \justifying          % layout of dedication paragraph

  }
  {\par                 % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{dedication}
  Dedicated to google and wikipedia by models (SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS), the CP provides the storage and processing facilities
  needed to support that service model, together with a cloud interface for cloud
  service consumers. For SaaS, the CP deploy.
\end{dedication}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a margin of 5cm for the left side?, sorry, please this change

Comment: @x-rw: Add the [`changepage` package](//ctan.org/pkg/changepage) and use the `adjustwidth` environment: `\begin{adjustwidth}{5em}{0pt}`...`\end{adjustwidth}`

Comment: yes it's ok, and how would I change if I want to use 'large', 'Large', 'LARGE'

Comment: @x-rw: You can use `\section*{\LARGE Dedication}`.