# How change the size the title 'Dedicatory'

Tags: fontsize

i have this code, and want change the size the title 'dedicatory' 20pts

```
   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
   \raggedleft          % Flush with right margin
   \section*{Dedication}% Formatting of dedication title (as section*)
   \itshape             % the text is in italics
   \justifying          % layout of dedication paragraph

  }
  {\par                 % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{dedication}
  Dedicated to google and wikipedia by models (SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS), the CP provides the storage and processing facilities
  needed to support that service model, together with a cloud interface for cloud
  service consumers. For SaaS, the CP deploy.
\end{dedication}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [How put title in dedicatory?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476651/5764)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
  \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
   %\raggedleft          % Flush with right margin
   %\section*{Dedication}% Formatting of dedication title (as section*)
   \begin{flushright}
    \fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\selectfont\bfseries Dedication
   \end{flushright}
   \itshape             % the text is in italics
   \justifying          % layout of dedication paragraph

  }
  {\par                 % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{dedication}
  Dedicated to google and wikipedia by models (SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS), the CP provides the storage and processing facilities
  needed to support that service model, together with a cloud interface for cloud
  service consumers. For SaaS, the CP deploy.
\end{dedication}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes it's ok, and how would I change if I want to use 'large', 'Large', 'LARGE'

Comment: @x-rw Substitute `\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\selectfont` with `\Large`, for example.